# How can I change which address Datastax agent will try to connect to?

Tags: datastax, datastax-enterprise

My Cassandra instances are not listening on `127.0.0.1`. When I start `datastax-agent` I find this in logs:

```
# tail -n 100 /var/log/datastax-agent/agent.log
...
ERROR [Initialization] 2015-05-19 22:35:04,064 Can't connect to Cassandra, retrying soon.
 com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /127.0.0.1:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.TransportException: [/127.0.0.1:9042] Cannot connect))
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.reconnectInternal(ControlConnection.java:220)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.connect(ControlConnection.java:78)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.init(Cluster.java:1231)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.init(Cluster.java:158)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connect(Cluster.java:246)
    at clojurewerkz.cassaforte.client$connect_or_close.doInvoke(client.clj:149)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:410)
    at clojurewerkz.cassaforte.client$connect.invoke(client.clj:165)
    at opsagent.cassandra$setup_cassandra$fn__8157.invoke(cassandra.clj:344)
    at again.core$with_retries_STAR_$fn__8013.invoke(core.clj:98)
    at again.core$with_retries_STAR_.invoke(core.clj:97)
    at opsagent.cassandra$setup_cassandra.invoke(cassandra.clj:339)
    at opsagent.opsagent$setup_cassandra.invoke(opsagent.clj:153)
    at opsagent.jmx$determine_ip.invoke(jmx.clj:276)
    at opsagent.jmx$setup_jmx$fn__8438.invoke(jmx.clj:293)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**How can I change which address the Datastax Agent connects to?** I have tried setting `local_interface` in the agent's `address.yaml` (and restarting agent), but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What address is your cassandra instance listening on? what does `netstat -an | grep LISTEN` return for port 9042?

Comment: It says `10.X.Y.Z`. That is, it gives a non-local address. In fact, it gives the the same address as specified in `cassandra.yaml` as `rpc_address`.

Comment: you can change rpc_address to 0.0.0.0 on all the nodes and restart cassandra. that will fix the issue for you. make sure you restart your seed node 1st.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The secret was to set `rpc_address` to `0.0.0.0`. Cred to LHWizard for pointing this out.